# Mean Value Theorem: Exponent and Natural Log

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, mean-value-theorem

**Question:**

Apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f(x) = 2^x = e^{x\ln 2}$ , show that $\frac{1}{2}\ln 2 < \sqrt{2} - 1$.

**Attempt:**

Using the Mean Value Theorem on $f(x)=2^x$ on the interval $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, we have:

$$f' (c) = \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{2} - 0} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\sqrt{2} - 2$$

Therefore, we have:

$$2\sqrt{2} - 2 = f' (c) = (\ln 2)2^c$$

Solving for $c$, we get:

$$c = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\sqrt{2}-2) < \frac{3}{4}\ln 2$$

Now, we just need to show that $\frac{3}{4}\ln 2 < \sqrt{2} - 1$. Squaring both sides, we get:

$$\frac{9}{16}\ln^2 2 < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$$

Subtracting $3$ from both sides, we have:

$$-\frac{9}{16}\ln^2 - 1 < -2\sqrt{2}$$

Dividing both sides by $-2\sqrt{2}$, we get:

$$\frac{7}{8\sqrt{2}}\ln^2 2 > 1$$

Finally, we can simplify the left-hand side to get:

$$\frac{7}{16}(\ln 2)^2 > 1$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{16}{7}(\frac{1}{\ln 2})^2$, we get:

$$\frac{16}{7} > (\ln 2)^{-2}$$

**Updated Attempt:**

Using the Mean Value Theorem on $f(x)=2^x$ on the interval $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, we have:

$$f' (c) = \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{2} - 0} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$f$ is an increasing function since $f' > 0$. Clearly $f'$ is also increasing. Therefore, for $c \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$, we have:

$$f'(c) < f'(\frac{1}{2}) = \ln 2$$

So, we have:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}} < \ln 2$$

Simplifying the left-hand side gives:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\sqrt{2} - 2$$

Substituting back in the inequality gives:

$$2\sqrt{2} - 2 < \ln 2$$

Adding 2 to both sides yields:

$$2\sqrt{2} < \ln 2 + 2$$

Dividing both sides by 2 gives:

$$\sqrt{2} < \frac{1}{2}\ln 2 + 1$$

Finally, we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln 2 < \sqrt{2} - 1$$

So, we have shown that $\frac{1}{2}\ln 2 < \sqrt{2} - 1$.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mean Value Theorem on $f(x)=2^x$ on the interval $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, we have:

$$f' (c) = \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{2} - 0} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$f$ is an increasing function since $f' > 0$. Clearly $f'$ is also increasing.
Therefore $f'(c) > f'(0) = \ln 2$, which completes the proof.

Comment: I read your suggestion and implemented it in my new answer, is that correct?

Comment: No, to start with $f'(1/2) =( \ln 2) * (\sqrt 2)$. Use $f'(0)$ instead.